# Bluetooth tethering between Android device and MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, tethering, android

I'm having some issues tethering my internet connection from an Android to my MacBook. It must be an issue with the MacBook, as it works on Ubuntu without a problem. A tried to re-pair the device and even remove the configuration from network settings and add it again but with no luck so far. Any ideas?

Comment: If you could please clarify *what you are trying to accomplish* by pairing the two devices. Are you looking to share files, set one or the other as a WiFi hotspot, or whatever you are attempting.

Comment: I'm trying to share the internet connection from the phone to my laptop.

Comment: Add it to your question, please

Comment: Added, it should be clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install a system extension called HoRNDIS in order for it to work.

Link: [HoRNDIS on GitHub](https://github.com/jwise/horndis)

UPDATE: macOS will be disabling system extension in the 10.16 version, so I have no idea what the solution will be then.